# Making multiple columns into one for .to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

Currently I have a code set up to read through a CSV file, but the CSV file has columns DAY, YEAR, and MONTH all as integers. I want to make them all one column of datetime64[ns] objects.

To make them datetime64[ns] objects, I did the following:

```
df.insert(0, "DATE", 0, True)
df["YEAR"] = df["YEAR"].astype(str)
df["MONTH"] = df["MONTH"].astype(str)
df["DAY"] = df["DAY"].astype(str)
cols = ["MONTH", "DAY", "YEAR"]
df["DATE"] = df["MONTH"] + "-" + df["DAY"] + "-" + df["YEAR"]
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this?
I'm new to pandas and coding in general, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [pd.to_datetime docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the columns you listed you should be able to do something like.

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY"]])
```

Can't say for sure without the data to try it on, but `pd.to_datetime` should be able to handle these columns without having to alter them.